# Haskell error - Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’

Tags: string, haskell, char

I am trying to write a Haskell function which would take a person's full name and return only the last name; for example, `getName "Hans Christian Anderson"` should return `"Anderson"`. The function is below:

```
getname :: String -> String
getname fullName = do
  let nameList = splitOn " " fullName    -- split the full name into individual names
  let reversedName = reverse nameList    -- reverse the full name
  let lastName = reversedName !! 0       -- get the first name from the reversed list
  return lastName
```

But whenever I try to compile this, I get the following error:

```
Couldn't match expected type ‘Char’ with actual type ‘[Char]’
In the first argument of ‘return’, namely ‘lastName’
In a stmt of a 'do' block: return lastName
```

I'm not sure I fully understand this error. As I understand Haskell (I am quite new to it) the structure `[Char]` would be the same as `String`, which is what I'm looking for. I just don't understand why it's expecting this `Char` type that it seems is appearing in the return statement as a String. I have gone over each line and they seem to be correct to me.

Any advice on why this behavior is occurring and how to fix it is much appreciated.

Comment: This is a great programming exercise. But [you might enjoy this cautionary tale about names](https://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).

Comment: @DanielWagner I have seen something like that before, and in fact I did consider how cautious I needed to be about the names I was dealing with so as not to get erroneous results. However, for the purposes of this exercise, it was acceptable for me to be a little heavy handed and go with a lot of those assumptions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use `do` notation here. Because the return value of your function is `[Char`], the argument to `return` is expected to be a `Char` value (because `return :: a -> [a]`).

You aren't doing anything here that requires `do` notation; just use regular function calls.

```
getname fullName = (reverse (splitOn " " fullName)) !! 0
```

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand why return behaves like this, but I think it's because I'm not thinking about it in a functional context based on my coding background. I didn't realise that using `do ... return ...` would yield any different result from using a regular function call but I will look into the documentation more. Thanks for your response!

Comment: That is the purpose of `return`; its general type is `return :: Monad m => a -> m a`, but `m` here is fixed to be `[]` because of the declared return value of `getname`. The `return` function is nothing like the statement of the same name in most programming languages

Comment: Yes, so it would seem, I think that's what threw me off. I expected it to behave the way I've always found it to behave.

Answer (score 2):

Your code is accidentally working inside the list monad, as if it was meant to describe a nondeterministic computation. You do not need that monad, nor any other monad. So, avoid using `do` for this. You can still use `let .. in ..` if you want:

```
getname :: String -> String
getname fullName =
  let nameList = splitOn " " fullName    -- split the full name into individual names
      reversedName = reverse nameList    -- reverse the full name
      lastName = reversedName !! 0       -- get the first name from the reversed list
  in lastName
```

Alternatively, use `last`:

```
getname :: String -> String
getname fullName = last (splitOn " " fullName)
```

Beware that `last` is partial: it will crash your program as soon as there is not name in the input string. A safer approach could be:

```
getname :: String -> Maybe String
getname fullName = case splitOn " " fullName of
   [] -> Nothing
   xs -> Just (last xs)
```

Or even:

```
getname :: String -> Maybe String
getname fullName = safeLast (splitOn " " fullName)

-- This should be already there in the library, IMO
safeLast :: [a] -> Maybe a
safeLast []     = Nothing
safeLast [x]    = Just x
safeLast (_:xs) = safeLast xs
```

Comment: Thanks for your response - in regard to safeLast, maybe you should actually suggest it to the Haskell community. Or failing that, I think they let just about everything on hackage!