# xmonad: Couldn't match type ‘Char’ with ‘[Char]’

Tags: haskell, types, xmonad

```hs
focusedWindow = spawn ("notify-send \"Focused on " <> readWindowName ++ "\"")

readWindowName :: String
readWindowName = let wn = runProcessWithInput "xdotool" ["getactivewindow getwindowname"] "" in wn
```

I'm trying to get the output of the process `xdotool` using the function [runProcessWithInput](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.17.1/docs/XMonad-Util-Run.html#v:runProcessWithInput), but the resulting error pops up:

```hs
xmonad.hs:236:121: error:
    • Couldn't match type ‘[Char]’ with ‘Char’
      Expected: String
        Actual: [String]
    • In the expression: wn
      In the expression:
        let wn = runProcessWithInput "xdotool" [...] "" in wn
      In an equation for ‘readWindowName’:
          readWindowName
            = let wn = runProcessWithInput "xdotool" ... "" in wn
    |
236 |                         readWindowName = let wn = runProcessWithInput "xdotool" ["getactivewindow getwindowname"] "" in wn
    |                                                                                                                         ^^
```

`readWindowName` needs to be a String as it is concatenated into a string inside `spawn` in `focusedWindow`. However, the function returns a [String], which is where I'm stuck at. Tried `unlines`, but I can't seem to make it work.

---

I also tried different methods of the same function, but they also don't work:

```hs
readWindowName' :: String
readWindowName' = do
    wn <- runProcessWithInput "xdotool" ["getactivewindow getwindowname"] ""
    return wn

readWindowName'' :: String
readWindowName'' = let wn = runProcessWithInput "xdotool" ["getactivewindow getwindowname"] "" 
                       wn' = unlines wn
                   in wn'
```

`readWindowName''` gives a different error:

```hs
xmonad.hs:236:51: error:
    • No instance for (MonadIO [])
        arising from a use of ‘runProcessWithInput’
    • In the expression:
        runProcessWithInput "xdotool" ["getactivewindow getwindowname"] ""
      In an equation for ‘wn’:
          wn
            = runProcessWithInput
                "xdotool" ["getactivewindow getwindowname"] ""
      In the expression:
        let
          wn = runProcessWithInput "xdotool" [...] ""
          wn' = unlines wn
        in wn'
    |
236 |                         readWindowName = let wn = runProcessWithInput "xdotool" ["getactivewindow getwindowname"] ""
    |
```

---

I did research about many others' exact problem (namely [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41000948/haskell-error-couldnt-match-expected-type-char-with-actual-type-char), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49611620/haskell-couldnt-match-type-char-with-char), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70448245/haskell-couldnt-match-type-char-with-char)), and I found that in the source code of `runProcessWithInput`, it uses the `return` statement, which (I believe) might be the problem in my code, mentioned [in this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49611655/19234665):

> `return :: Monad m => a -> m a` is used to wrap a value (of type a) in a monad.

Is there any way to get around this or a different function that I haven't discovered yet other than editing the `runProcessWithInput` source code?

Comment: `runProcessWithInput` actually returns an `m String` for any `m` that can perform IO, indicating that its value could change with time (making it impure). You can't just use it as a `String` because it might not be the same the next time you use it. Changing the type of `readWindowName` to `IO String` should do the trick.

Comment: @fluffyyboii That certainly makes sense, thanks. Changed the type to `IO String` and the initial error is gone, but the function still needs to be a `String` type. I still can't quite grasp on how to use this type in order to concatenate it into a string; I read answers ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16197901/19234665) [2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11230235/19234665)) relating to this, but my mind isn't clicking.

Comment: You might need something like `do wn <- readWindowName ; spawn ("notify-send \"Focused on " ++ wn ++ "\"")`. The type of this will be `IO ()`. Note how IO is viral: if you use something IO-based, you need that definition to have an IO type. This is how Haskell forces the programmer to mark all the code parts that do IO in their types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, after some time off this problem, it turns out that the solution was simpler than I thought.

```hs
focusedWindow = do
    wn <- runProcessWithInput "xdotool" ["getactivewindow", "getwindowname"] ""
    spawn ("notify-send 'Focused on " ++ wn ++ "'")
```